# Wikipedia: dump article id's and it's category

Tags: mysql, dump, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I would like to make a mysql database with every wikipedia article id and it's category id (most general category). I saw that wikipedia gives an entire dump, and a few others like links between categories. Also I saw there is mediawiki but I can't manage to find the right query to send.

But nonetheless I can't find how to dump a big file with the article id's and it's category id. 
How should I do it?
How much data should I expect?

Comment: How are you going to find out which category is the “most general” one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia provides dumps of most of its data. The one that you want is `categorylinks.sql`, which contains list of category names (categories don't have IDs) for each article ID. You will also most likely want `page.sql`, which contains map from article ID to its title.

To work with the dumps, you can import them into a local MySQL database, or you could use a library that parses the dumps directly, like [the one I wrote for .Net](https://github.com/svick/Wikipedia-SQl-dump-parser).

But each article is usually in several categories and there is no notion of primary category or anything like that. So, if you really want just one category for each article, you will have to figure out how to do that by yourself.

Answer (score -2):

use the wikipedia API : http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

article id=736 and categories: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=categories&titles=Albert%20Einstein

Comment: Is there a way to give it just an article id and to get returned the category id (most general)?

Comment: This won't work if you want to do this for *every* Wikipedia article.

Comment: @DnX: No there is not. MediaWiki has no concept of "most general category" and I expect even you would be challenged to define it.